# Asymptotics of $\sum\limits_{n/2 < p \leq n} \frac{1}{p}$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I'm reading a paper which asserts the following:

$$\sum_{n/2 < p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} \sim \frac{\log 2}{\log n}$$

follows from prime number theorem, where the sum is taken over $p$ prime. What is the explanation for this? I tried working it out using

$$\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log(x)}$$

but didn't get anything useful. Sorry if this question is easy, I don't have much experience with ANT.

Comment: Did you read Apostol's book?

Comment: @DeepSea I have not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a more information than just the PNT. What we need the following refined form of PNT.

$$
\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\log x}+O\left(\frac x{(\log x)^2}\right).
$$

We can write your sum as (apply partial summation)
$$
\int_{n/2}^n \frac{d\pi(t)}t  = \frac{\pi(n)}{n} - \frac{\pi(n/2)}{n/2} + \int_{n/2}^n \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2} dt
$$

Now, using the form of PNT above, we have 
$$
\int_{n/2}^n \frac{d\pi(t)}t = \int_{n/2}^n \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2} dt + O\left(\frac1{(\log n)^2}\right).
$$

Using the form of PNT again, we have
$$
\int_{n/2}^n \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2} dt=\log\log n - \log\log (n/2) +O\left(\frac 1{(\log n)^2}\right)$$

Since $\log\log n - \log\log(n/2) \sim \frac{\log 2}{\log n}$, we have the result.

Comment: Good A. From the integral form of the PNT, if $f:R^+:\to R$ is monotonic and $f(x)=O(x^n)$ as $n\to \infty$ for some $n\in N$ then $\sum_{p\leq n} f(p)\sim$ $ \int_2^n(f(x)/\ln x)\; dx.$